# Using Streamwriter Append not working

Tags: append, streamwriter

Hey All my code is set up like this..

```
Method()
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"file"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Service Start {0}", DateTime.Now, true);
        }

Method () 
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"filet"))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Service Stopped {0}", DateTime.Now, true);
        }
```

My text file isn't getting appended, instead it is getting replaced. I thought setting true was suppose to append the files but it hasn't.
This is a c# windows service App

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(@"file", true);
```

With this overload of the StreamWriter constructor you choose if you append the file, or overwrite it.

Comment: thank you, NotCoding's solution worked but not for the first line using his in conjunction with yours solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what do you have that assumption?

It pays not to assume things like this.  [Read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fysy0a4b.aspx) and see what it says.

> The path parameter can be a file name, including a file on a Universal Naming Convention (UNC) share. If the file exists, it is overwritten; otherwise, a new file is created.

Use a different constructor, such as one that uses a stream.

Answer (score 0):

I was not aware that that was what that overload was supposed to do... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamwriter.writeline.aspx

Instead try this way:

```
    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("yourfilename"))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("Service Stopped {0}", DateTime.Now, true);
    }
```